# Does the R.java file declarations consume spaces from the 64K limit?

Tags: android, r.java-file, dex, android-multidex

I wonder if does the `R.java` file declarations/assignations consume spaces from the 64K methods limit?

Maybe because of the set/get of the variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `R` class and its subclasses don't have normal methods, but they do typically have a no-op constructor method, and possibly also a static constructor method which is used to initialize some of the fields that can't be initialized statically in the dex file.

So, assuming you have roughly 10 classes counting the `R` class and its various subclasses (`R.string`, `R.layout`, etc.), you'll end up with about 10-20 additional method references.

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` does not contain methods, only `static` fields. There is a 65,536 limit on both methods and fields but they are separate. 99% of the time you will hit the method limit before hitting the field limit.

If you need it, I added the functionality to count the number of fields in the [dex-method-counts](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts) library.

Comment: Not quite true. They can have a constructor and static constructor, which do  end up in the method reference list in the dex file.